# how to find if incomming parameter in not null and not empty in Sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

I am trying to write some thing like this in sybase ASE

```
@searchstring varchar(500)
    If(IsNULLorEmpty(@searchstring))
    {

    exec(@strexecsql)

    }
    else
    {

    exec(@strexecsql1)

    }
```

what is best way to check this condition IsNULLorEmpty for a incoming @parameter?

Comment: Why have you tagged `oracle` and `plsql` if you are using `Sybase`? What data type is `@Parameter`?

Comment: In the documentation there is a sub-section about using [Variables and NULL values](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/X65478.htm) inside a control block such as `IF/WHILE` etc. The entire section is probably of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best would be ISNULL, i.e.:

```
DECLARE @searchstring varchar(500)
...
IF(ISNULL(@searchstring,'') = '')
    EXEC(@strexecsql)
ELSE
    EXEC(@strexecsql1)
```