# How to ensure variable is not null in sybase sql procedure?

Tags: sql, sybase

How can I check for (not) null in sybase sql procedure?

The following code:

```
if @name is not null
  begin
    print "test !!!!!!!"
end
```

This does not work because of a syntax error.

How can I check that @name is not null? What's the correct syntax?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find if incomming parameter in not null and not empty in Sybase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29077854/how-to-find-if-incomming-parameter-in-not-null-and-not-empty-in-sybase)

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage)? what's the complete/exact text of the syntax error? from an ASE perspective, there's nothing wrong with the code snippet you've posted so we're going to need more details; at this point I'm wondering if some other part of the stored proc is generating a syntax error ... unfortunately we don't have the complete text of the stored proc nor the text of the error message you're receiving ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @name varchar='sa';
if ISNULL(@name,'')!=''
   begin
      print ('test !!!!!!!');
    end
else
     print ('Name is null');
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21908789)

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to comment that why I have put a code.